# postgres + sequelize + node, connection to host with credentials

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to access a postgres db on a remote server using sequelize and I dont' know how.

I tried a couple of methods but none have worked.

I have this config file :

```
{
  "postgres" : {
    "ip": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx",
    "port": "5432",
    "user" : "hostUser",
    "password": "hostPassword",
    "db": {
      "name":"dbName",
      "username": "dbUsername",
      "password": "dbPassword"
    }
  }
}
```

and I have this tried those methods

Method 1:

```
let sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://'
  + config.user + ':' 
  + config.password + '@'
  +  config.ip + '/' 
  + config.db.name,
  config.db.username,
  config.db.password,
  {
    dialect : 'postgres'
  }
)
```

output:
`error: password authentication failed for user`

Method 2:

```
let sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.db.name,
  config.db.username,
  config.db.password,
  {
    host: config.ip,
    port: config.port,
    dialect : 'postgres'
  }
)
```

output:
`connect ECONNREFUSED`

Method 3:

```
let sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.db.name,
  config.db.username,
  config.db.password,
  {
    host: config.user + ':' + config.password + '@' + config.ip,
    port: config.port,
    dialect : 'postgres'
  }
)
```

output:
`getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`

versions:

node: 7.7.3

pg: 6.1.5

sequelize: 3.30.2

postgres: 9.5.6

Answer (score 1):

the steps to resolve this were as follows:

On the remote server:-

1- `find \ -name "postgresql.conf"` to find place of config file

2- `sudo nano /path/to/config/postgresql.conf` to edit config file

3- change this `#listen_addresses = 'localhost'` to this `listen_addresses = '*'` then save and exit

4- `find \ -name "pg_hba.conf"` to find hba config file

5- `sudo nano /path/to/config/pg_hba.conf` to edit hba config file

6- add 

`host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
host    all             all              ::/0                            md5`

at the end of the file, then save and exit

7- run `/etc/init.d/postgresql restart` to restart postgres

In the code connect like this:-

```
let sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.db.name,
  config.db.username,
  config.db.password,
  {
    host: config.ip,
    port: config.port,
    dialect : 'postgres'
  }
)
```